# How to develop Case Manager widget in local envrionment?

Tags: ibm-content-navigator, ibm-case-manager

Thank you for viewing my question.

We are using IBM Case Manager(ICM) 5.2. There are new change from users. I am the BA/developer.

To modify the existing Case Manager Plugin and custom widgets, I have to do the following tasks:

1. Change the ICM widget JS and HTML codes, on my local environment with Eclipse.
2. Replace the JS and HTML from the (custom) widget package, send the updated package to application server.
3. On the server, use the Case Manager configuration tool to deploy the package.
4. Login Case Builder and deploy the solution. Test the code and revert back for testing.

---

---

My questions are:

(1). I don't know how to run these codes on my local environment without deployment into ICM. Is it a must to install a Case Manager in my local envrionment?

(2). Is there an easy way to test and debug Custom Widgets JS & HTML codes from my local environment?

Regards!

Comment: I would not change the standard widgets but rather overload the current definitions with new ones, and for the debugging, just use firebug(or IE dev tools or chrome, whatever you like)

Comment: Thanks your reply @Robert. Yes, ICM plugin will not be changed. At this topic I want to discover how to develop custom widgets.

Comment: I do not know if its fully applicable for case, but this redbook http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248055.html?Open has excelent examples for navigator and the additional materials link also has a navigator developement plugin, to aid in scaffolding your widget projects

Answer (score 0):

In order to be completely run and configure widgets locally, you'll need a complete installation of ICM. This is due to the fact that you'll heavily rely on both Content Navigator as Case Manager resources. You might be able to test a thing or two by requiring remote resources, but in the end you'll need to integrate your widget on a running installation to be able to actually use it in the page designer.

By far your easiest option is to locally build your widget, then remotely deploy and remote debug.

Assuming you know how to deploy your widget (use the Config mgr, or the icmadmin desktop), then by far the easiest way to debug the front-end, is using the "developer tools" that come with most browsers (IE/FireFox/Chrome). Simply hit the F12 button, locate your .js file and place a breakpoint. Consult your browser's help/google on how to use the tools.

Debugging the java part of your widget can best be achieved by creating a remote debug session in eclipse to your application-server. In eclipse go to "Debug Configurations", then add a new "Remote Java Application", choose your "Widget Project" and fill in the remote ip/(debugging)port of your application-server. Press Debug and you're set! Place breakpoints and invoke your java :)

Additionally see this blogpost with additional tips for debugging + screenshots: [Debugging your ICN plugins (or ICM widgets)](https://www.ivojonker.nl/?p=468).